# Semantics: Conditional Distribution vs Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability

This is something which has always confused me.

Suppose we take a standard statistical regression model:

\begin{equation}
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

where:

- $Y_i$ is the response variable
- $X_i$ is the predictor variable
- $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the coefficients
- $\epsilon_i$ is the error term.

The error term $\epsilon_i$ are assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and constant variance $\sigma^2$, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

Given this information, we can find out the Expected Value of $Y_i$:

\begin{align*}
E(Y_i) &= E(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i) \\
&= E(\beta_0) + E(\beta_1 X_i) + E(\epsilon_i) \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 E(X_i) + 0 \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i
\end{align*}

Given this information, we can also find out the Variance of $Y_i$:

\begin{align*}
Var(Y_i) &= Var(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i) \\
&= Var(\beta_0) + Var(\beta_1 X_i) + Var(\epsilon_i) \\
&= 0 + \beta_1^2 Var(X_i) + \sigma^2 \\
&= 0 +0 + \sigma^2 \\
&=  \sigma^2 \\
\end{align*}

Using the mathematical properties of the Normal Distribution (i.e. linear combinations of Normal Distributions are also Normally Distributed), we usually write the following:

\begin{equation}
P(Y_i) \sim N(\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

**My Question:** When I look at the above formula, I always think that this is referring to the Marginal Probability Distribution of $Y_i$. But since this distribution depends on ${x}_i^T $ , is this not actually the Conditional Distribution?

Thus, I think it would be more correct to write the above formula as:

\begin{equation}
P(Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i) \sim N(\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

**Can someone please tell me if I am correct?**

Thanks!

- **Note:** Assuming the analysis I provided here is correct - this analysis can serve to clarify one of the common misconceptions in Probability: In a standard regression model - $Y_i$ by itself does NOT need to have a Normal Distribution! But rather, $Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i$ needs to be Normally Distributed!
- This means that if I plot a histogram of the response variable (i.e. $Y_i$) and it does not look Normally Distributed - this in and of itself is not a solid indication that a standard regression model is not suitable. Rather, we need to study the conditional distribution $P(Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i)$ before making such conclusions.

Comment: In your post, you are treating $X$ as fixed. But yes, if $X$ were random and independent of $\epsilon$, then it would be correct to say that $Y_i$ has regular conditional distribution $\mathcal N(\beta^TX_i,\sigma^2)$ conditional on $X_i$

Comment: @AndrewZhang : Thank you for your reply! In the regular use case, X is not random. So in the post I made, is it incorrect to say: Yi has regular conditional distribution N(βTXi,σ2) conditional on Xi?

Comment: @AndrewZhang : If X were random : Do you mean that if X had a Probability Distribution? Or do you mean if the subjects that you are using to measure X are chosen randomly?

Comment: $X$ random as in not constant. One can condition on a constant, and so you technically could say $Y$ conditional on $X$, but it is customary that this implies $X$ is random.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am still a bit confused. Usually we write : P(Yi given X=xi)   is this what you mean by X is fixed?

Comment: If you have time, can you please write an answer and explain this in more detail?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to state the classical linear model: $$y_i = \beta^T X_i+\epsilon_i,\quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$
, where the $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ and independent of $X_i$. $\beta\in \mathbb R^p$ is the target of inference. We observe $X_i,y_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ is unobservable. At this point, one can either make the modeling assumption that the $X_i$ are fixed numbers, i.e. constants, or that the $X_i$ are in fact random. Depending on the application, both viewpoints are natural.

For example, in signal processing, one could imagine that they are observing a signal at different points in time, these observations are corrupted by noise $\epsilon_i$. What is being observed here is $y_i$. Now, any signal $f(x)$ can be represented using a basis in $L^2$, say $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \beta_k \varphi_k(x)$. In the classical model, we are assuming that all but finitely many of the coefficients $\beta_k$ are non-zero.

To make this more explicit, we observe $y_i = f(x_i)+\mathrm{\,noise}, i\in[n]$, at time $x_i = i/n$, namely we assume that $f(x_i) = \beta_1\varphi_1(x_i)+\dots+\beta_p\varphi_p(x_i)$.  To summarize, this is a natural setting where we model the covariate vector $X_i$ as fixed. For more on this viewpoint, see these notes: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5557.pdf

Now consider the first documented use of linear regression, Galton's study of the relationship of the height between father and son. Here, $y_i$ is the son's height and $X_i = (1, \text{father(}y_i)\text{ height})$. It does not make sense here to think of $X_i$ as being fixed, here we must view $X_i$ as random.

Onto some semantics, when one writes $y_i \mid X_i \sim \mathcal N(\beta^TX_i,\sigma^2)$, it is customary that this implies $X_i$ is random. Of course, there is nothing in mathematics that says that the statement $y_i\mid X_i \sim \mathcal N(\beta^TX_i,\sigma^2)$ is wrong when $X_i$ is deterministic, just as there is nothing in mathematics preventing $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ from representing a sequential limit. But the convention is that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ represents $x\in \mathbb R$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ represents $n\in \mathbb N$. In other words, if your model is that $X_i$ is deterministic, you should write $y_i \sim \mathcal N(\beta^T X_i,\sigma^2)$, and if $X_i$ is random, then $y_i\mid X_i \sim \mathcal N(\beta^TX_i,\sigma^2)$.

Finally, a word on conditioning. If we take $X_i$ to be random, then once we condition on $X_i$, it has the same effect as treating $X_i$ as deterministic. There is a subtlety here, which is that $\epsilon_i$ must be independent of $X_i$. Let's consider the general case $W = g(U,V)$ and you condition on $U$. Then it turns out that conditional on $U = u$, $W$ has regular conditional distribution $g(u,V_u)$ where $V_u$ is a random variable which is distributed according to the regular conditional distribution of $V$ given $U=u$. Now, $V$ is independent of $U$ if and only if the distribution of $V_u$ is the same as $V$ for (almost) all $u$.

Returning back to the original setting, conditioning on $X_i$ has the effect of making $X_i$ constant if $\epsilon_i$ is independent of $X_i$. This is a point which is often glossed over in the literature.